# Having difficulty in saving all the mask from the results generated by a model

Tags: python, opencv, yolov8

I have implemented a YOLOv8 model and was able to make the predictions. Now, I want to extract and save all the masks from the results of the model. For this purpose, I have composed the following code.

```
model = YOLO(model_path)
dest_folder = '/path/to/the/folder'
results = model.predict('path/to/the/test/images', save=True, imgsz=448, conf=0.75, visualize = False, show_labels=True, show_conf=False,show_boxes=True)
for result in results:
  for j, mask in enumerate(result.masks.data):
    mask = mask.numpy() * 255
    mask = cv2.resize(mask, (W, H))
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dest_folder, 'result_'+str(j)+'.jpg'), mask)
```

This piece of code saves the instance of a single result. What changes will complete the desired task? Any help will be highly appreciated.